# How to run electrical wire and ad a junction box to a concrete ceiling

Tags: electrical, wiring, concrete, ceiling

I have been reading through some of the answers as this question was previously asked.  So will try to keep it short so that you all can give me just a yes or no answer to my question.

Condo concrete ceilings walls are drywall electric exist where i can get the power from run behind drywall up to ceiling, then CONCRETE.

if management says that there are nothing hindering how would one run the wire and a junction box to put in a fan or light.

question 1.
could One chip away a trench that will accommodate flat electric rated conduit from the wall to center of room?
Question 2. do i need to chip away the concrete deep enough to fit the junction box??

thank you all

Comment: Add your location, maybe city to your question, so the experts can give right answers according to your local electrical code.  Think you should see this link for some ideas.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51330/how-to-run-electrical-wire-in-concrete-ceilng?rq=1

Comment: im looking to do this in Fort Lauderdale Fl

Answer (score 2):

### Surface raceway is the way

Generally, on exposed concrete/masonry surfaces, one uses a surface conduit or raceway (Wiremold™ or equivalent) run, attached to the surface using concrete anchors, along with matching surface-mounted boxes.  So, no, there's no need to start chipping into the concrete just to have a ceiling lamp or fan in the room.

Comment: Thank you, but aesthetically i do not want to see the conduit or any wiring.  could one chisel and make a trench (so to speak) and chisel away deep enough to put in a junction box without it protruding almost 3 inches.  Again this would only be done if the building management approves.  Thanks again!

Comment: @BillDonadio  Quite sure your Florida condo management will allow you to chisel into structural concrete of the the building.

Comment: @BillDonadio -- I'm pretty sure from here the answer your management will give is "heck no, just use surface raceway, Wiremold isn't *that* ugly"